# How does form API work for CCK (and other #after_build processes)?

Tags: forms

When you want to hook into a CCK form and alter something, you are usually required to call a custom function from `$form['#after_build']` (right?).

When doing so, I have noticed I can't write $`form['field_name']['#disabled'] = TRUE;` but instead I have to use the `#attributes` approach.

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form API is usually doing that for you, but it probably does that before calling the after_build functions.

The #after_build functions are called in [form_builder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_builder/6), #disabled handling is in [_form_builder_handle_input_element()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/6), which is called earlier in form_builder().

Comment: can i use #pre_render or #process instead of #after_build? would it make any difference?

Comment: Not sure, some specific fields like those from date.module are only really built in #after_build functions, so you need to do your changes in such a callback too. Not sure about others. But if #pre_render works, you can probably also simply do your changes in hook_form_alter().